# Не работает trigger('click') для owl-carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Зддравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отправить событие нажатия кнопкой мыши для owl-carousel, событие должно быть именно по слайду, не по навигации, должно работать именно как клик (в плагине есть апи через которое к выбраному слайду прокрутить, но оно не подходит)

Comment: Что должно происходить по нажатию на слайд?

Comment: Например есть магазин http://baby-comf.ru/collection/frontpage/product/kolyaska-2-v-1-mima-xari-flair-2g-black-shassi там есть галлерея http://prntscr.com/gklt4v , которая меняется с помощью селектора модификаций http://prntscr.com/gkltap сейчас работает с помощью апишки, но вылетают баги, должно нормально работать при имитации клика, но ничего не происходит (само событие вызывается, но owl никак не реагирует)